# Substring index as function guard

Tags: erlang

I'm implementing a function and I need to know if a string contains a substring as a guard. I have tried the following:

```
myFunc(Number, String) when N rem 2 == 0, string:str(String, "pattern") == 0 - > do thing....
```

With that structure, I'm getting an illegal guard expression, but I have not clue why is happening this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm getting an illegal guard expression'

In erlang, you can't call just any function in a guard, e.g. string:str(). Erlang only allows a very restrictive set of function calls to be used in a guard.  See section [8.25 Guard Sequences](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html).

However, you can use a case statement inside the body of the function to execute a function call that is illegal in a guard, then examine the return value:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

func(N, Str, Pattern) when N rem 2 == 0 ->
    case string:str(Str, Pattern) of
        0       -> io:format("The string '~s' does not contain the pattern '~s'.~n", 
                             [Str, Pattern]);
        Index   -> io:format("'~s' contains the pattern '~s' at index ~w.~n", 
                             [Str, Pattern, Index])
    end.
```

In the shell:

```
29> c(my).                            
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

30> my:func(4, "HelloWorld", "cat").
The string 'HelloWorld' does not contain the pattern 'cat'.
ok

31> my:func(4, "HelloWorld", "World").
'HelloWorld' contains the pattern 'World' at index 6.
ok
```